# How to force GitHub Windows client to ask where to clone a repo every time?

Tags: windows, github, settings, clone

I want GitHub client to ask me where to clone a repo each time I'm going to clone it from GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [release notes](http://windows.github.com/release-notes.html) for the 1.0.18 version of GitHub for Windows" includes:

> Added: "`clone to...`" menu item for cloning to a specific base directory

So if you select *that* menu entry (**right-click** on a repo), it will ask you where to clone your repository. Every time.

[image: GitHub for Windows clone to option]